# Port a MEF class library to netstandard 2.0?

Tags: .net, mef

I have a small class library built in Framework 4.7.1 that uses MEF. Specifically, it includes:

`ComposablePartCatalog`
`AggregateCatalog`
`CompositionContainer`
`DirectoryCatalog`

Can I port this to a Netstandard 2.0 library?

Clearly these classes are not present in the API. Is there a NuGet package or something I can migrate to?

And in general, will these classes or replacements exist in Netstandard at some time?

Comment: Not sure why you need such, but MEF itself has .NET Standard 1.5 support, https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-mef/issues/15 You might open an issue there to consult.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the tip ... It is such a small library I was hoping to find abstractions that allowed me to define it in NetStandard and use it in Core and Framework projects. I tied to abstract it myself --- it exposes MEF types in interfaces --- but that has proven to be nontrivial!

Comment: I hope this will help. http://blog.softwarepotential.com/porting-to-net-standard-2-0-part-2-porting-mef-1-0-to-mef-2-0-on-net-core/

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by using a Microsoft preview Mef package on MyGet.org. It's:

System.ComponentModel.Composition
4.5.0-preview1-26002-01

As of today.